# Getting list of file names from GIT repo from Spring cloud config server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I am using Spring cloud config server with GIT which is working fine as expected.

Now, my requirement is to get the list of filenames from the spring cloud server.

Spring cloud config only provides API like http://localhost:8088/myconfig/default/master/config.properties to get the property values.

Is there any API available to get all file names? If not, what would be the alternate approach?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately it's not possible. The way we did in our project - added properties with needed file names in config.properties and fetched files in the code using

> additional endpoint at /{name}/{profile}/{label}/{path}

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_serving_plain_text